# JavaScript how to create a assertion to test if a string list include some sub-string

Tags: javascript

I have a string list(error message list) looks like following

```
[
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.firstName of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.lastName of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.mobilePhone of required type PhoneInput! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.email of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.gender of required type Gender! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.username of required type String! was not provided."
]
```

how can check if the in that string list include 
...any substring.... "firstName" ...any substring... "was not provided" ....any substring...
thanks

Comment: I have added a solution below. Just so you know, there is already a question like this on stack overflow located at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) testing each item with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
const input = [
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.firstName of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.lastName of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.mobilePhone of required type PhoneInput! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.email of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.gender of required type Gender! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.username of required type String! was not provided."
];

let res = input.some(x => /.*firstName.*was not provided.*/.test(x));
console.log("At least one message match? " + (res ? "YES" : "NO"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.includes() is an easy way to search each array item for the sub string.
Example for firstName below.

```js
var errorArray = [
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.firstName of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.lastName of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.mobilePhone of required type PhoneInput! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.email of required type String! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.gender of required type Gender! was not provided.",
  "Variable \"$staffMemberInput\" got invalid value {\"dateOfBirth\":\"1980-01-01\"}; Field value.username of required type String! was not provided."
];

let nameError = 'firstName';
let errorDescription = 'was not provided';
for(var i = 0; i < errorArray.length; i++){
 if(errorArray[i].includes(nameError) && errorArray[i].includes(errorDescription)){
  console.log(nameError  + " " + errorDescription);
 }
}
```

Simply check for any other values while looping through the array.
Hope this helps.